Existed account is not shown on explorer
I have this account: https://explorer.solana.com/address/E8a2qSSEoe5pShCYnRuxbdxmNhFsqeuWFrsQW7iZNtUh. In explorer, it show that account is already closed.
But when I fetch it using code or cli, it show the data: 
Furthermore, when I crate that account again, it show that Account is already exist 
And the problems is when I use that account on-chain, account can't be used. The account is an associated token address.
Anyone experiences this situation, please help me. Thank you guys

Just add Minimum Rent balance and you should be able to start using the account.
Minimum Rent in SOL: 0.00203928 atm

If the balance of associated account is zero, then it will be closed.
So in the explorer, this account will be closed due to balance.
When you are going to recreate, please check both mint address and authority address.
And also have to check balance.
If you are using anchor framework
you can use this contrains
 init_if_needed

